# How to determine the owning table of a column returned by a SQLite query in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am using `System.Data.SQLite`. I am writing a C# program that reads data from any given SQLite database.
This program runs a number of queries over the given database. I query the `sqlite_master` table to determine the tables in the database and then run `PRAGMA` statements to get the schema of each of the tables.

My main problem is; when I do a `SELECT * FROM table_1 JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.id;` I cannot find a way to determine what table each of the id columns come from.

I am hoping that someone will be able to point me in the direction of being able to determine the table that each column in the query result is from.

I have been able to obtain the data in a `NameValueCollection` which does not handle the duplicate column names in the way I would have liked. I would have liked a dictionary with the table name as a key with a dictionary of columns as the value; example below:

```
{"table_1": {"col_1": value, "col_2": value}, "table_2": {"col_1": value, "col_2": value}}
```

Or a qualified column name so I could access the items like:

```
reader["table_name.column_name"];
```

I have also been able to obtain the data from the query in a DataTable, which does not obtain the data in a way I would have liked. The id column from the example above is simply appended with a number 1 to indicate that it is duplicate.

The two functions I use to return the NameValueCollections and DataTable are below:

```
class DatabaseReader
{
    private string ConnectionString;

    public DatabaseReader(string ConnectionString)
    {
        this.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a NameValueCollection of the query result
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="query">The query to be run</param>
    public IEnumerable<NameValueCollection> ExecuteReader(string query)
    {
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand();
        command.CommandText = query;

        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(this.ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            // Do things with the open connection
            command.Connection = conn;
            SQLiteDataReader reader;
            using (command)
            {
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            }

            if (reader != null)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    yield return reader.GetValues();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("{0} query returned nothing"));
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a DataTable of the query result
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="query">The query to be run</param>
    public DataTable GetDataTable(string query)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(this.ConnectionString))
            {
                cnn.Open();
                using (SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(cnn))
                {
                    mycommand.CommandText = query;
                    using (SQLiteDataReader reader = mycommand.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        dt.Load(reader);
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
                cnn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
        return dt;
    }

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in your SQL query. you have to set a name for each column that you want to retrieve from the tables. so you can use this query:

```
SELECT table_1.ID as Tbl1_ID, table_2.ID as Tbl2_ID FROM table_1 JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.id;
```

now you can read each column value by it's name, for example:

```
reader["Tbl1_ID"];
```

or it's index, like:

```
reader[0];
```

Comment: This is quite a good workaround. However, when I am running this query, I do not know the columns that are present in the table (this could be programmatically figured out) and I am always wanting all of the columns, hence why I was doing a `SELECT * FROM...` statement.

Comment: This is a reason why you should not use `SELECT *`.

Comment: Yeah, maybe this will all work better if I go back to the drawing board and get rid of the `SELECT *`

Comment: @MichaelMurphy when you execute a query, the result will be simple table and contain only columns name and columns value. there is no extra data about `where was the data retrieve from`. so if the query result will be different every time, I think you should change your database design to make it simple to execute queries.

Comment: I don't think I have been clear. I don't know the database that the tool will be used with, hence the use of generic SQL statements and why I am querying the sqlite_master table to obtain information on the tables that are present in the database. I am going to redesign some stuff tonight to see if I can remove the generic statements.